# Problems calling pandas_datareader

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I would like to install and use pandas_datareader from anaconda, but I am having some trouble. I am installing the package in the same manner as I always do:

```
conda install pandas-datareader
```

The package installs just fine and when I check to see that it is installed with

```
conda list
```

the package is listed as the most recent version of 0.5.0 and is for py27_0.

Then if I try something like

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

I always get the following import error

```
ImportError: No module named pandas_datareader
```

I have tried importing datareader from a script and with ipython but I can't figure out why this would be giving me an error.

Comment: Apologies for checking the obvious - but were the conda install/list definitely run in the same conda environment as you were in when trying to do the import?

Comment: @E.Gordon no worries, they were run in the same environment. Even as a sanity check I exited re-activated the environment, checked that everythign was installed and tried running again.